# what is different between funcname(); and return funcname(); in onsubmint property of form?

Tags: javascript, function, onsubmit

I'm making moving ball program. 
When I put into "onSubmit();" in onsubmit property of form,
nothing happened. But I want to look moving ball that happens with function excuted.
And nothing error occured in console.

```
<form id="f" onsubmit="onSubmit();"><input type="submit" ></form>
```

After that I modifyed my code like this.

```
<form id="f" onsubmit="return onSubmit();"><input type="submit" ></form>
```

Still nothing happened.
After Finding book, I find putting into function return false.
this code is my second modification and work correctly.

```
function onSubmit() {
  if (animate == false) {
    var tev=setInterval(move, 500);
    animate=true;
  }else{
    clearInterval(tev);
    animate=false;
  }
//this code was inserted in second modifycation.
  return false;
}
<form id="f" onsubmit="return onSubmit();"><input type="submit" ></form>
```

My Question is two things.
First, what is different between funcname(); and return funcname(); in onsubmint property of form?
Second, What is role of //return false in onSubmit function?

Comment: If you return false, the form will not submit. You need to return true for the form submission to happen. This is why the `onSubmit` function is often used for form validation.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `function()` you are saying to execute the function onSubmit.

When you say `return function()` you are saying to continue submit depending on the return value of function(). **If function() returns false, submit doesnt continue.**

Your case returns false if no conditions are satisfied. Then submit won't be success.

*It is mostly used for validations, for example when you want some required fields you can return false unless there are not empty values.*

Comment: Thank you for your explain. I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need the return so the true/false gets passed up to the form's submit event (which looks for this and prevents submission if it gets a false ).
 And that is it according to your role of function if it has to return something or only excuted with no return.